# Changing X-Original-To: header in postfix

Tags: linux, postfix

I am using a virtual file with my postfix to redirect all mails coming to my domain to a user

My virtual entry looks like this

```
@domain.com root
```

Now the X-Original-TO header shows root@domain.com. I want to set in such a way that the X-Original-To field to show the mail id by which the mail is originally sent.

For eg: if a user tries to mail user8@domain.com. The user8 does nt exists in the server. According to my virtual file, it will be forwarded to root@domain.com. and the X-Original-To header will be showing as "root@domain.com". I want it to show as user8@domain.com

Answer (score 0):

I have my server setup similarly, however, I use `luser_relay` to redirect unknown local addresses.

`luser_relay = root@example.com`

I do not use `alias_maps`. With this I get the wanted `X-Original-To:` header.

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#luser_relay